# How can filter parent based on children in django

Tags: django, filtering, django-queryset

I have this

```py
from django.db import models

class Kid(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Toy(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Kid)
```

I have this queryset

`kids = Kid.objects.all()`

Now I want to filter kids whole toys has name `star` in it

and I am not able to decide which filter to apply

`kids.filter(toys_set__icontains='star')`

Comment: @alecxe sorry that was typo

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
Kid.objects.distinct().filter(toy__name__icontains='star')
```

Note the `distinct()` method.  It is required because kid can have several "star" toys so without `distinct()` you will get duplicates in the queryset.

If you want to filter kids by number of found toys when use [aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/aggregation/#following-relationships-backwards):

```
Kid.objects.distinct().filter(toy__name__icontains='star') \
                      .annotate(toys_num=Count('toy')).filter(toys_num__gt=4)
```

Comment: but Kid don't have any toy field. isn't it `toy_set`

Comment: @thanks for clearing my doubt. how can i query where kid has more than 4 toys